# Как написать функцию генераций запроса sql для получения данных с определенными критериями?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Таблица mysql:

```
id, category_id, name, bestseller, novelty, discount
```

С фронта мне приходит get запрос с параметрами, например

```
{
 categories: [1,2],
 bestseller: true,
 discount: true,
 novelty: '',
 page: 1
}
```

Для отсеивания пустых ключей использую данный код:

```
const sortOptions = {};
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  if (data[key] !== '') {
    sortOptions[key] = data[key];
  }
});
```

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы сгенерировать sql запрос из полученных данных, а так же получить кол-во записей для пагинаций. 
Сейчас я вижу для себя писать условия для каждого из возможных вариантов событий.

```
let sql = '',  countSql = '', conditionPromo = '';

if (sortOptions.bestseller &&
    sortOptions.novelty &&
    sortOptions.discount) {
  conditionPromo = 'bestseller = 1 OR novelty = 1 OR discount = 1';
} else if (...) {...} // И таких условий множество


const condition = `${
        sortOptions.categories ? 'category_id IN (:categories)' : ''
      } ${conditionPromo.trim() !== '' ? `AND ${conditionPromo}` : '' }`;

sql = `SELECT * FROM goods WHERE `id` > :id ${conditions.trim() !== '' ? `AND ${conditions}` : ''}`;
countSql = `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM goods ${conditions.trim() !== '' ? `WHERE ${conditions}` : ''}`;
```

К тому же я считаю свое решение не на 100%, ведь данные могут приходить по разному и допустим где-то 'AND' будет лишним к примеру. Подскажите стоит мне продумывать сейчас все возможные события или можно решить задачу намного проще?

Answer (score 1):

(без синтаксиса)

Сразу делаешь

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM goods WHERE 1=1";
```

а потом , если какой-то параметр фильтра задан - конкатенируешь его в запрос в правильной форме и с корректным квотированием, если требуется, и не забывая про разделительный пробел:

```
if (discount <> '') {
    sql += " AND discount=" + discount;
}
```